# No notification when guard-rspec is used with spork

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, spork, libnotify

I am working on ubuntu machine with Ruby-1.9.2 and rails-3.1.3. I am using guard-rspec for autotesting and spork as DRB server.

When I run guard without spork, it shows the correct notifications. But guard with spork shows no notifications at all.
Here is relevant part of my Gemfile

```
group :test, :development do
    gem 'rake', '0.9.3.beta.1'
    gem 'turn'
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'rspec'
    gem 'guard-rspec'
    gem 'spork'
    gem 'webrat'
    gem 'rb-fchange'
    gem 'rb-fsevent'
    gem 'libnotify'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it is an old question, but found via Google and just struggle with same problem.

Solution is quite easy.

Use guard-spork (https://github.com/guard/guard-spork)

```
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'libnotify'
```

Add at the top of Guardfile (before rspec definition):

```
guard 'spork' do
  watch('config/application.rb')
  watch('config/environment.rb')
  watch(%r{^config/environments/.*\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^config/initializers/.*\.rb$})
  watch('Gemfile')
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb') { :rspec }
  watch('test/test_helper.rb') { :test_unit }
  watch(%r{features/support/}) { :cucumber }
end
```

run

```
bundle exec guard
```

Comment: That worked for me too (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS), thanks! Can you explain what the change to the guard block does and why it's needed? I'm still trying to get to grips with ruby on rails etc.

Comment: Found matching tutorial code: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages?version=4.0#sec-spork_and_guard