# Libnotify not displaying notifications when using Spork and Guard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spork, guard, libnotify

Libnotify was working fine on my system (Lubuntu) until I started using guard-spork.

My Guardfile:

```
notification :libnotify

guard 'spork', :wait => 60, :rspec_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' } do
  # ...
end

guard 'rspec', :version => 2, :all_after_pass => false, :cli => '--drb' do
  # ...
end
```

My Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rb-inotify'
  gem 'libnotify'
  gem 'spork'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
end
```

What could I be doing wrong here? I run `bundle exec guard`, spork is working fine, my tests are all passing, but the notifications are not showing up through libnotify. I'm using latest gems.

Comment: I got the answer from I got the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/a/10164046/10245, I think this question might be a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

restarting my machine fixed this, as it does in 99.99% of situations